# svg native support

Tags: graphics, svg

I have been extensively using LaTeX for technical documentation. To make drawings I often use inkscape and then convert them to .pdf. I was wondering, are there any plan in LaTeX community to natively support the SVG format?

I saw there is a possibility to include [the SVG package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/svg). I did not try it but as I understood from manual it does exactly the same thing as I do: it calls inkscape, converts svg->pdf and includes the resulting image via pdflatex. I don't see any added value in that, as this only makes the document compilation longer and more complex.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: You mean, the possibility to write something like `\begin{svg}\rect{x="10" y="10" height="100" width="100" style="stroke:#ff0000; fill: #0000ff"}\end{svg}` and get a picture? That would be great!

Comment: tikz uses a tex rather than than svg/xml syntax but implements many of the drawing primitives found in svg, bezier curves, fills, gradients etc

Comment: I think the question is asking about being able to do `\includegraphics{<existing svg filename>}` just as we do for `.jpg`, `.png`, `.eps`, etc. today.

Comment: There is `svg` package, if you mean...

Answer (score 7):

Short answer I think is "no" there are no plans.

Over the years there have been several requests for different formats, notably gif images and EPS.  However given that the end result has to be a PDF stream including any new format essentially means linking some xxx-to-pdf conversion library into the pdftex executable which makes it bigger and harder to maintain and doesn't really add much real functionality as, as you comment, you can do the conversion from a wide array of formats externally, targeting pdf for vector formats or png for bitmap.

As an alternative to conversion from SVG you could look to generating the relevant PDF drawing operators directly in TeX, which is basically what the tikz/pgf code is doing.

tikz uses a tex rather than than svg/xml syntax but implements many of the drawing primitives found in svg, bezier curves, fills, gradients etc..

Comment: Yet, pdflatex accepts png, jpg, ... are they native to the pdf format? ;-)

Comment: @Arnaud jpg yes png  no but it is native to pdftex it has a built in png convertor so as far as latex graphics is concerned it is a native format (it is also a lot slower than jpg or pdf to include because of the conversion)

Comment: Thanks David for you answer of my comment to your five years old answer! It is quite useful to learn that using png slows down the compilation process. I use lots of png images in some of my articles.