# How to add social icons to a non-moderncv resume?

Tags: xetex

I am using Deedy Das's resume template and would like to include links to my GitHub, Quora, and LinkedIn accounts. Is there any way to include those icons in the resume file?

Comment: `\usepackage{fontawesome}` I think

Comment: But you have to use XeTeX and the font must be installed on your system.

Comment: Neither did `fontawesome` :/

Comment: Is there any way to natively embed SVGs? Quora doesn't seem to have a fontawesome icon :/

Comment: You may look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/222911/17423 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2099/17423, but your best bet is to just convert the SVG into a PDF and use `\includegraphics`.  I would wrap such a call in a macro as such: `\newcommand\Quora{\includegraphics[height=1.5ex]{thingy}`.

Comment: @SeanAllred Wanna write up an answer? Remember, there are (at least) [five different instances of the template](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion/blob/master/exampleDeedyResume.md) out there.

Comment: @Johannes_B I'll take a stab tonight

Comment: @SeanAllred Meow